# Ajax global variables or synchronous AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, global-variables

I want to get data from another page using AJAX. I also want to wrap this AJAX call into my "user defined function".

But I can not write like this:

```
 function func(){
      var tmp;
      $.ajax({
          url: 'url',
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",

          success: function (data) {
            tmp=data;
          }
     });

     return tmp;
}
```

because AJAX is asynchronous and this code returns - "undefined".

When AJAX async param set to **false**

```
var tmp=$.ajax({...});
```

possible do the trick.

I also can create some global variables and write like this:

```
function setMyVariable(){
        $.ajax({
          ...
          success: function (data) {
            myGlobalVariable=data;
          }
        });
}
```

The question is -  **Is it good practice to use global variables in this case?**

Or it is completely wrong and I need search something else

Comment: Well, as you can see in your first example, it sometimes won't work and yield `undefined`. So it's definitely a **bad practice**.

Comment: have you read [how to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572) already?

Comment: you should not use globals or sync ajax, use callbacks and async techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to return the promise from `$.ajax`:

```
function func(){
      var tmp;
      return $.ajax({
          url: 'url',
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
     });
}
```

Then you can do `function().done(function(result) { ... } );`

Comment: It works just once. If I call func() again - nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean it works once? The AJAX call is only fired once?

Comment: .done part works once and then it get complete state (or I don't now why) and next func() calls or ajax calls do not run .done part again